# Nokia E50 and mac internet sharing

Tags: macos, nokia, internet-connection

I am using a nokia E50 and imac. my imac is connected to the internet. i want to share my internet connection to my E50 too via bluetooth. is there any way to do this. help needed..

is there any third party application which does the same? ie, which provide an option to share the internet of a desktop.!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The handset doesn't contain a bluetooth access point configuration. It is also missing the software components that would allow this. You won't be able to do this without writing quite a lot of software yourself.

One solution would be to purchase some WiFi access point hardware to share your home internet connection amongst several devices, or to get a femto cell device from your mobile network operator.

Comment: But Nokia E50 don't have a wifi connectivity

Comment: unfortunate indeed. time to figure out whether your mobile network operator makes you pay for data connections that your phone would make via a femto cell using your home network.